# broken ffmpeg default settings detected

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, video-capture, h.264, libx264

I am getting broken ffmpeg error while VideoWrite using X264 Fourcc codec.I have install all the dependencies.How can I rectify this problem.The sample code that I have been using is as follows.

```
VideoWriter oVideoWriter ("path.mp4", CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'), 15, frameSize, false);
```

Operating system : Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Console Error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Could not open codec 'libx264': Unspecified errorOpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Your version of Gstreamer doesn't support this codec acutally or needed plugin missing.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/mbox140/Development/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 518
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/mbox140/Development/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:518: error: (-210) Your version of Gstreamer doesn't support this codec acutally or needed plugin missing. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open
```

Suggest me any solution for this.

Comment: What is the actual `ffmpeg` command (if using the cli tools and not the API)? What is the actual, complete `ffmpeg` console/log output?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have updated my question with console log,Please look into this

Comment: Please show the **complete** console output and the command too if possible.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input_file -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -y output.mp4

i am using this command , getting same error

Comment: Are you insisting on h264? You could try using some other codec, such as MJPG for example.

Comment: Maybe your gstreamer is out of date?

Comment: Is the video playable? If your settings are wrong in OpenCV, it will create an ill-formatted video.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to ensure you have the latest version of the libx264 codec. You can do this by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall x264 libx264-dev
```

The error also indicates an issue with GStreamer not having the necessary plugins. You can install GStreamer plugins using:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```

Answer (score 0):

for the error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0x8d6220] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
```

you may need the command -vpre perset (e.g. -vpre fast).
maybe you libx264 is too old.
I meet the same error while using a ffmpeg built in 2014.

Comment: Since libx264 is called indirectly, there is no way to give additional ffmpeg switches on any command line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if you need to re build `opencv` with open `h264` support, but for sure, standart `opencv` doesn't provide `h264` codec. 
Here is a hint:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/104346/how-to-encode-a-h264-video-on-windows/

Comment: The question is about OpenCv on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

please install libx264-dev and try compiling openvc3.0 with that. follow this [link](https://github.com/intel/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide)